# Having Trouble Installing Pillow in PyCharm using Anaconda enviroment

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install pillow for a project I am doing using PyCharm and Anaconda and having some trouble...  Basically, when I try to install pillow in my anaconda environment it says that pillow is already downloaded. However, when I am running code in PyCharm it says that pillow is not installed and asks me if I would like to install it. I click install package and this is the error I get:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.


PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pil

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/sunpy/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/sunpy/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cctbx/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/cctbx/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I have tried using different channels using:

```
conda config --append channels (whatever channel)
```

The channels I have tried using are sunpy and cctbx

I am a bit confused with this so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just need to use `pillow` instead of `pil`. Seems like a simple little mistake but dang... really goofed me up.